# Using OleDbConnection to Read Tab-Separated File

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, text-files

My tab-delimited file is something like this:

```
ISO ISO3    ISO-Numeric
AD  AND 20
```

I've been trying the following code with no luck.

```
OleDbConnection cn = new  OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= |DataDirectory|;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=TabDelimited'");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM countryInfo.txt", cn);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

cn.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Here's a screenshot of the Dataset Visualizer. Its obviously not the output i'm after.
[image]

Any suggestions? Here's my Schema.ini file. Its in the same directory as the text file.

```
[countryInfo.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

Should i just use something like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) instead?

---

@Hans Passant Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I always parse the file myself.

Comment: I worked with these a few years ago, so I'm pretty rusty. But I do remember that the schema.ini had to be in the same directory as the data file. Also, having a # sign in the front column "may" be a problem, but I'm not sure. It might interpreting your column header line to be commented out.

Comment: Schema.ini is in the same folder. Also i tried removing the # sign but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one obvious candidate is that this white space isn't actually a tab but spaces.  Try FMT=Delimited( ).  Use a hex viewer to see what's really there.  Backgrounder [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx).

And [this thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/9f7d2b67-cea5-4840-96ef-2e12011752d7) shows why using a buggy chunk of code like Jet that hasn't been supported for the past 9 years is such as mistake.  With the answer, leave the first line in schema.ini blank.

Comment: FMT=Delimited( ) didn't work. When i open the file in a hex editor i see '.' between fields. What does that really mean?

Comment: You are supposed to see hex numbers, not dots.  Post a screen shot.

Comment: No clue what "bh" might mean, that was the point of asking for a screen shot.  09 is indeed the ascii code for a tab.

Comment: Yes its 09. Screenshot above.

Comment: It is tab delimited.  The file is encoded in utf-8, probably too advanced for JET.  The 1st 3 bytes in the file is the BOM, that's what produces the # in the output.  You could open the file in notepad and save it back with Encoding set to ANSI.  See if that makes a difference.  I don't really get the 'all jumbled together' remark btw.

Comment: Saved it back in ANSI but even that didn't make a difference. What i was trying to say was that delimited fields weren't properly separated in my output. I'll re-edit the question with my full code and a screenshot of the output. I'm sure this is all to do with something stupid on my part, this is the first time i'm using OleDb to read this sort of a file.

Comment: No idea.  Check this thread: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/9f7d2b67-cea5-4840-96ef-2e12011752d7

Comment: Wow that's it! If i leave the first line of the schema.ini file blank and start [filename] from the second line, it works! Thanks heaps. I'm going to mark yours as answer, and it'd be great if you can add that link to it.

Answer (score 2):

Create and save an schema.ini file into the application folder containing the following text:

```
------------------Schema.ini file starts here-----------------
[Data.txt]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=TabDelimited
Col1=First_Name Text
Col2=Middle_Initial Text
Col3=Last_Name Text
------------------Schema.ini file ends here-----------------
```

Then use the following code to load the Data.txt file:

```
string fileName = string.Format("{0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);   
string connectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; " + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=TabDelimited;\"", fileName);
string sql = "select * from " + "Data.txt";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "Data";
dap.Fill(dt);

con.Close();
```