# I have a *.tsv file which contains 32 million records and I need to load them and do search operation

Tags: c#, .net, csv, filehelpers

When I load the file it throws me 'OutOfMemoryException'. How can I load and do search efficiently?

I am using

```
//to load the file.
var passEngine = new FileHelper<MyClass>.ReadFile().ToList() 
var passList = passEngine.ReadFile("Files/plain_32m.tsv");
```

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Open as stream and search as you seek the stream.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 I also need to cast them in 'MyClass'.

Comment: That;s fine, just don't try to do them all together. Read a reasonable number at a time, process, and read more while discarding what is already processed. This is how streaming is done. You pretty much never would open a large file even a fraction that size and slurp it all.

Comment: Sounds like a great use case for a database...do you have to stream the file?  If you did a bulk insert to Sql Server it would be quick and then easily indexable / queryable (as well as having the benefit of being persistent)

Comment: Perhaps you could use an OLE DB Connection for this? That would allow you to run queries against the file as if it were a database.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063685/using-oledbconnection-to-read-tab-separated-file

Answer (score 0):

Code below adds data to a datatable.  It also assumes the first row contains the names of the columns

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"Files/plain_32m.tsv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] tsv = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }).ToArray();
                //remove any end spaces from data
                tsv = tsv.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

                if (++rowCount == 1)
                {
                    foreach (string colName in tsv)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(tsv);
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider approaching it in couple of ways

**Method 1:**

If it is one time search operation and pick only small set of records from large file, you can do so with streaming approach along with Linq to objects. there are number of open source libs available to care for it.

I'm going to show you one such library, [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/)

```
using (var p = new ChoCSVReader<MyClass>("*** Your CSV File ***")
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    )
{
    var subset = p.Where(rec => rec.ID == 100).ToArray(); //You can apply any filter
}
```

**Method 2:**

Load the file to database. This approach is useful if your search criteria is complex, and improving the search with indices etc. You can load the file either with EF / BulkCopy / ADO.NET. BulkCopy is preferable for such large file. Sample code shows how to load the file using Bcp

```
string connectionString = "*** DB Connection String ***";
using (var p = new ChoCSVReader<MyClass>("*** Your CSV File ***")
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    )
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
    {
        bcp.DestinationTableName = "** DB Table Name **";
        bcp.EnableStreaming = true;
        bcp.BatchSize = 10000;
        bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        bcp.NotifyAfter = 10;
        bcp.SqlRowsCopied += delegate (object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.RowsCopied.ToString("#,##0") + " rows copied.");
        };
        bcp.WriteToServer(p.AsDataReader());
    }
}
```

Once you have loaded file to database, rest you can do like creating indices, querying and filtering the data via EF/ADO.NET etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

FileHelpers has a `FileHelpersAsyncEngine` which allows you to work record by record and avoid reading or writing all the records at once. The documentation is [here](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadWriteRecordByRecord/).

```
var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<Customer>();

// Read
using(engine.BeginReadFile("Input.txt"))
{
    // The engine is IEnumerable
    foreach(Customer cust in engine)
    {
        // your code here
        Console.WriteLine(cust.Name);
    }
}


// Write     
using(engine.BeginWriteFile("TestOut.txt"))
{
    var arrayCustomers = GetSomeMoreCustomers(); // a batch at a time
    if (arrayCustomers.Count() > 0)
    { 
        foreach(Customer cust in arrayCustomers)
        {
            engine.WriteNext(cust);
        }
    }
}
```